# I want to find the rate of change of height of water in this question

Tags: derivatives

> An empty container of length $12 \ \textrm{cm}$ and the vertical cross
>   section of it is an isosceles right angled triangle.
>
> If the water poured in it at a rate $\frac{10 \
>  \textrm{cm}}{\textrm{sec}}$ find the rate of change of height of water
>   in the container when the depth of water is $2 \ \textrm{cm}$.

I´ve  found that the volume of container $= 6 \cdot  (\textrm{"side length of triangle"})^2$.

But I don't know how to continue ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please do not just post your homework questions with no effort. Show us what you've tried to do and where you have a specific question.

Comment: Have you made a sketch?